# Python3 Regex Split Issues (Splitting by IP Address

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to split a file by IP addresses to grab blocks of data using re.split. The IPs of the data will be dynamic, so I decided to use a regex expression so I can split it by any group of IPs. I've tried it with two separate expressions:

```
testfile = re.split("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d?\d)(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}$", filetext)
#and
testfile = re.split("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1?\\d?\\d)(?:\\.(?!$)|$)){4}$", filetext)
```

I have gotten no luck.

The full code is below.

```
file = open('test.txt') # Load file into variable
filetext = file.read()
#print(filetext)
testfile = re.split("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|1?\\d?\\d)(?:\\.(?!$)|$)){4}$", filetext)
#testfile = filetext.split('10.10.10.10')

print(testfile)
```

Everything gets returned into a list, but does not split by IP address. Here is a example of the results [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muQ2S.png)

Also here is a sample of test data:

```
10.10.10.10
hostname:
stuff:    2

stuff:
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- keyword
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
10.10.10.11
Hostnames:
stuff:    2
stuff:
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- keyword
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
10.10.12.10
Hostnames:
stuff:    2
stuff:
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- keyword1
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
10.10.10.10
Hostnames:
stuff:    2
stuff:
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- keyword2
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
    data ----- junk
```

Comment: Did you search `python ip regex site:stackoverflow.com` and try any of the numerous patterns?

Comment: This is why you check your regexes with something like https://regex101.com because your first code block's first regex works perfectly fine. The one in the actual code with the file read, however, does not work at all. So just fix your code to use the regex that works